# AWS EventBridge triggers SageMaker pipeline successfully but says failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-event-bridge

I have a SageMaker pipeline set up to transform audio data and run a model training script.  We are using custom containers for both parts if that matters.  The pipeline runs end to end when I test it in SageMaker with no issues.

I set up an EventBridge rule to trigger the pipeline overnight at regular intervals.  This triggers the pipeline successfully, but in my invocations dashboard it appears that the jobs fail.

I'm using the default event bus.  The execution role has all Read, Write, and List on my pipeline's ARN.

While the pipelines appear to run successfully, it would be nice if I could rely on the dashboards in the EventBridge console.  Is there anywhere else I should be looking to debug?

[image: Failed Invocations]

[image: SageMaker Pipelines are Successful]

Comment: I would recommend cutting a support request to dig more into this https://aws.amazon.com/support

Comment: Do you see anything in CloudWatch indicating why EventBridge failed? It's best to cut a support ticket.